# belongs_to - undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

First of all I show you how I add the belongs_to association:

**user.rb:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  [...]
  has_many :schedules
  [...]
end
```

**schedule model: (console-command)**

```
rails g model Schedule user_id titel location time
```

**schedule.rb:**

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**routes.rb:**

```
Calendar::Application.routes.draw do
  [...]
  resources :users, only: :index
  [...]
end
```

**welcome_controller.rb:**

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @schedules = current_user.schedules
  end
end
```

**welcome\index.html.erb:**

```
[...]
  <% if current_user %>
      <%= for schedule in @schedules do %>
          <strong><%= schedule.titel %></strong>
          <%= schedule.time %>
          <%= schedule.location %>
      <% end %>
  <% else %>
[...]
```

db:migrate works fine.
**Result:**
**Exception:** *undefined method `schedules' for nil:NilClass*

```
def index
   @schedules = current_user.schedules
end
```

---

Well, there is no schedules-method. But I did it as **Rich Peck** said and I think he knows how to do it.
For better understanding I should add the first [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23570341/need-help-at-dynamic-table-content-plan-in-rails-4).
Short Information:
There is a html-table which should have a this content: Header-Date, titel, time, location.
As you can see, it's a schedule.
The schedule-model belongs_to a user_model.
I want to use the schedule-model in the welcome-index-view.
I hope you have all the information, which you need to help me.
Can anyone help me to fix it ?

---

**EDIT:**

**application_controller.rb:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :current_user

  def current_user
    # Note: we want to use "find_by_id" because it's OK to return a nil.
    # If we were to use User.find, it would throw an exception if the user can't be found.
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_authentication_token(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token] && @current_user.nil?
    @current_user
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you use `devise` gem? or have `current_user` custom helper?

Comment: I do not use devise. Yea there should be a current_user helper.. let me check that. -> Check the EDIT.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your associations and everything to do with the back that `current_user` is nil

Comment: Where you save this `session[:user_id]` or this `cookies[:auth_token]`?

Comment: @FrederickCheung: It's just too simple :D Thanks for your help. Maybe you want to add an answer, so that I can check this question as answered.

Comment: @Зелёный: I don't know how to answer it.. Sorry, but maybe this will help you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/575551/User-Authentication-in-Ruby-on-Rails#Sessions46

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **Frederick Cheung** said there isnt any problem with the association.
The problem ist that the *current_user is nil*, so that I fixed it like this:

**welcome_controller.rb:**

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if(current_user)
      @schedules = current_user.schedules
    end
  end

end
```